# Wrongly got exit stamp from Schengen zone

Tags: visas, spain, eu, german-residents

I am an Indian passport holder with a German residence permit. I was traveling to Barcelona, and in the airport one of the security misguided me and I went past immigration and got stamped. Then I realized that was for boarding flights outside Schengen zone. I then told the situation to the police who guided me back through the transit and there was an entry immigration again and my passport got stamped after checks and questions. And I was able to enter again. I have an exit and entry stamp within 10 min.

I am just in a bit of a panic mode after this incident. Could any of you let me know, if there will be any impact on my immigration status or the residence permit?

Comment: Relax. This can't have any negative impact on anything. Residence permit holder ARE allowed to travel outside of the EU / Schengen. This "trip" was very short, but that's not a problem.

Comment: The correct procedure would have been to cancel (with 2 lines through the Euro symbol) the exit stamp, since you did not leave the Schengen Area. Be it as it may, this will have no side effects for you in any way shape or form.

Comment: @MarkJohnson it would certainly have been correct to do as you describe, but it isn't entirely incorrect, either.  I have a pair of stamps like this on an old US passport somewhere.  It only makes a difference for holders of single-entry or dual-entry visas.  For everyone else, the added administrative burden of processing it as a cancellation of departure is probably not justified.

Comment: There will be no problem. Everyone would know it was a mistake at the airport, since who would leave a continent for only 10 minutes?

Comment: @phoog Agents are more used to seeing exit and entry stamps than a cancelled stamp. It may actually have saved OP hassle of someone checking on the validity of the cancelled stamp, since that's much rarer.

Answer (score 28):

There are visa types that have a limited amount of entries (usually 1 or 2) but you have a residence permit which does not have such a limit. Your residence permit allows you to leave and reenter the EU as often as you want. You got the stamp showing reentry so everything is in order now, nothing to worry about.